# Rearrangements of the word "COMBINATORICS" that don't begin with 'I'

Tags: discrete-mathematics

I have a question that asks how many times can the word COMBINATORICS be arranged that there isn't any arrangement that begins with the letter 'I'.

I firstly have figured the amount of times that the word can be rearranged without any conditions which was

13! / (2!x2!x2!)

Can someone help me with the next part and that's finding the arrangements that don't begin with I?

Comment: Just subtract the number of arrangements that *do* start with I.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No. of combinations in total = A = $\frac{13!}{2!2!2!}$ (as you have rightfully stated)
No. of combinations beginning with "I" = B = $\frac{12!}{2!2!}$
No. of combinations not beginning with "I" = A-B = $658627200$

Is it okay?

Comment: That makes sense, I've been trying it with the same method, but with 11!/2!/2! and was always giving me a wrong answer so I doubted my method. I just tried your solution and it worked. Thanks.